# python + mysql - Creating via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to create python + mysql service for simple development environment and download some information from internet.

I don't want to create new build every time, therefore I want to use bind mount for python source code.

My catalog is: 'python_mysql'.

I created there: docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3.6'

    services: 
      python:
        image: python:latest
        ports:
         - '80:80'
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: .
            target: /scripts
      mysql:
        image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
        volumes:
          - type: volume
            source: mysql-db1
            target: /var/lib/mysql


    volumes: 
      mysql-db1:
```

I have named volume also - database file : mysql-db1 - i want to used it.

```
    $ docker volume ls 
    DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
    local               mysql-db1
```

After:

```
    $ docker-compose up -d
    Creating network "python_mysql_default" with the default driver
    Creating python_mysql_mysql_1  ... done
    Creating python_mysql_python_1 ... done
```

have:

```
    $ docker container ls -a
```

https://gyazo.com/b355c686db87ef0bfabbffad0ee19b37

```
    $ docker volume ls 
    DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
    local               mysql-db1
    local               python_mysql_mysql-db1
```

1) How to use the mysql-db1, not create new one ?

2) How to start python with bash command ? I want interact / go into python container and make something. It is possible without creating dockerfile ?

3) Whether bind mount is done well ?

4) Why in python container I don't see ports 80:80 ? Will the python container have an internet connection via 'request' module?

5) I dont understand top level 'volumes:' command. Can anyone explain to me on the basis of my example?

Comment: What do you mean by `Why in python container I don't see ports 80:80`?

Comment: $ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                 NAMES
1ad46f892ce1        python:latest               "python3"                5 seconds ago       Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                                python_mysql_python_1

PORTS is empty
please see link

Comment: That is because your container exited, so no more port mapping as the container is not alive any more

Comment: ok, so this is answer for 4) - thanks.
So i want to keep them alive. Best solution for me would be run python with bash command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) How to use the mysql-db1, not create new one ?

It will only be created only once until unless you delete it using `docker-compose down -v` or some other command. So if it doesn't exist it is created

> 2) How to start python with bash command ? I want interact / go into python container and make something. It is possible without creating dockerfile ?

You need to launch a command which doesn't end without user input. The default `python` command will exit without the same. So you need to probably a command like

```
command: tail -f /dev/null
```

And then later use below command to launch python or bash

```
docker-compose exec python python
```

or

```
docker-compose exec bash
```

> 3) Whether bind mount is done well ?

Not sure what it means, but it looks good if it works

> 4) Why in python container I don't see ports 80:80 ? Will the python container have an internet connection via 'request' module?

You container exited that is why `80:80` is not show

> 5) I dont understand top level 'volumes:' command. Can anyone explain to me on the basis of my example?

It is to specify the volumes your compose file use. Like `mysql-db1`, you can control parameters about the same. You can say `external: true` which means your composition expects a volume to be already present and wont create it and you can even specify which plugin to use for volume. If you use the same

Comment: After your tips, my file looks like this: 
https://gyazo.com/dfbb8b617898a1885a33e1198f759e6e

Unfortunately, I can not connect to the database. What could be wrong?
https://gyazo.com/db1c2253a6c3965c62485a8d3fecaaf8
`mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`

Comment: You should use `mysql` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/bf02c0acf1405a15f9f4cdaead563d2a
`mysql` or `python_mysql_mysql_1`
unfortunately, the problem is still there
`mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1130 (HY000): Host '172.18.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`. $ docker network inspect python_mysql_default 
https://gyazo.com/41770522f781f90e0a2c5fefe6dc66e0

Comment: You not defining some required environment variables in your docker-compose. You need to define `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` and set the value is ROOT. I think you DB is either not getting up or generating a RANDOM password

Comment: I have set MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
I can get to the base using `docker-compose exec mysql mysql -uroot -proot`